# Alternative to time delay while installing exe through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sendkeys, powershell-5.0

I have a software exe which I am trying to install via PowerShell. It's working fine. I am using `SendKeys` to navigate through the installation GUI. I have given delay between two `SendKeys` commands, because software takes some time between two steps, but that installation time varies from computer to computer.

My question is how can I bypass this time delay dependency in `SendKeys`? I have tried `AppActivate` but its of no use for me. Is there any alternative to delay?

Comment: Isn't there another way to install the software (like parameter parsing)? Could you post some of you current code to get a better view on the problem?

Comment: Also what Powershell Version are you using? I doubt that you use both v2.0 and v3.0 on you device

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to code of the software. Its a private company's software so I can't have the source code. I use powershell V5 on Windows 10 ENT.

Comment: Well start calling the installer like this `install.exe /?` and look if it shows installation triggers

Comment: There are two option regarding installation. /Exenoui and /exebasicui, but both launches same gui installation.

Comment: Lots of comments about initiating the installation from the CLI. I won't rehash. To your question, you're using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` to send key strokes to an installation wizard. You've got delays (`Start-Sleep -Milliseconds ...`) so the script waits for a given window before sending the key strokes. On different systems, that wait period varies. You want to ditch the waits and just figure out if "the form" has loaded. For MDI, I'm not sure. For SDI apps, try http://www.niteshluharuka.com/how-to-list-the-name-of-current-active-window-in-c/

Comment: My recommendation is to get a proper installer from the developer. If that's not possible, install on a clean machine, track changes to registry and file system, and then create a proper installer.

Comment: @Adam This is for c#...Can it be used in powershell?

Comment: Correct, yes, the example is in C#. You'd need to adapt this for Powershell, and you can. You can make Windows API calls from Powershell (run a search in Google, and you'll get a bunch of articles on the subject). I'd give you sample code, but I'm reluctant to add that as "an answer".

Comment: @Adam If thats the case let me try it out.

Comment: @Adam can you give me any sample code...after 3 days I am still unable to use windows api in Powershell to get my desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

I've converted [Nitesh's C# function](http://www.niteshluharuka.com/how-to-list-the-name-of-current-active-window-in-c/) to a Powershell script

```
$signature_user32_GetForegroundWindow = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
"@

$signature_user32_GetWindowText = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
"@

$foo = `
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature_user32_GetForegroundWindow `
        -Name 'user32_GetForegroundWindow' `
        -Namespace 'Win32' `
        -PassThru

$bar = `
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature_user32_GetWindowText `
        -Name 'user32_GetWindowText' `
        -Namespace 'Win32' `
        -Using System.Text `
        -PassThru

[int]$nChars = 256
[System.IntPtr] $handle = New-object 'System.IntPtr'
[System.Text.StringBuilder] $Buff = New-Object 'System.Text.StringBuilder' `
    -ArgumentList $nChars

$handle = $foo::GetForegroundWindow()
$title_character_count = $bar::GetWindowText($handle, $Buff, $nChars)
If ($title_character_count -gt 0) { Write-Output $Buff.ToString() }
```

There is a lot going on here. Lemme explain a little of what I did.

1. I've created two method signatures (the bit in the here-string); one for each function we're calling.
2. I use those signatures to create corresponding types. Again, one for each method.
3. For the GetWindowType (which passes the title back in a string and needs a reference to System.Text), I pass in the `System.Text` namespace in the `-Using` parameter.
4. Behind the scenes, PowerShell adds references to the `System` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices` so no need to worry about those.
5. I create my string size (`$nChars`), window pointer (`$handle`), and window title buffer (`$Buff`)
6. I call the functions through the type-pointer: `$foo...` and `$bar...`

Here is what I get when I run all this...

[image]

Whenever I have to call the Windows API (which isn't really my thing), I reference the following two articles:

- [PowerShell P/Invoke Walkthrough](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/)
- [Use PowerShell to Interact with the Windows API: Part 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/25/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/)

I hope this helps!